# OpenGL glMatrixMode rotation

Tags: opengl, java, camera, lwjgl

I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to rotate the viewport(or camera). So far I've figured out I need to use the function `glRotatef` and `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`. But I have no idea how to apply the rotations to the model view. I'm sorry I have no code to show because I have no idea how to get started. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of rotating the camera, you can rotate an object as well.
But for the reference, you can check out this project made by me.
Hope this will clear most of yor queries.

http://code.google.com/p/3dtouchmovingcube/

Comment: You should just read **any** tutorial.

Comment: What are you talking about. Most tutorials I find don't cover camera work...

Answer (score 1):

glRotatef should apply to whatever matrix is currently selected by glMatrixMode. Just execute it after glMatrixMode.

It's worth nothing that [glMatrixMode is a deprecated command](http://www.davidbishop.org/oglmeta). The new way of doing things involves using shaders, binding a matrix to them and multiplying them together with the vertex coordinates.